# Apache vhost php access

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have set up an Apache httpd with Xampp.

I created two vhosts:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

     DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/voice
     ServerName voice.server.de
     ServerAlias voice.server.de

 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>

     DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/pics
     ServerName pics.server.de
     ServerAlias pics.server.de

 </VirtualHost>
```

The first vhost works perfect. Its filled with .php files (index.php).
The second (pics) doesn't work with .php files. Only .html files will open in my Browser.

If i set the DocumentRoot from the second Vhost to the directory of the first, it works.

Both folders have the same permissions.

What can i do?

EDIT:
I think its a Problem with wordpress.

I can access the www.server.de/wp-admin/install.php but not the main directory www.server.de

I can access a phpinfo.php file in the maindirectory.

Comment: You do not need to have both `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` if the names are the same only `ServerName` should be enough. You need to enable PHP within your `VirtualHost`, probably just need to use the `directory` directive for that.

Comment: but the first vhost works with php an if i set the documentroot of the second vhost the same as the first.. it works to.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in one and not the other?

Comment: there is no .htaccess file in any folder under xampp/htdocs

Comment: The settings you've shared do nothing to enable PHP in either sites. Also, "does not work" is not a useful description (of course it doesn't or you'd not be asking here). How does it fail to work?